# Where to find Kibana system log file in Windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, kibana-7

I have installed kibana on windows 10 using .zip folder suggested at [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/windows.html)

I have updated `kibana.yml` to store log as below.

[image]

I have log folder created as well. I restarted kibana using cmd as well. But nothing shows in log file.

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Leads are appreciated.

Comment: Did you remove the comments `#` from the configuration file options? They are commented out in your screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested it and Kibana 7.9.2 in Windows 10 (Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763) and logging is working correctly.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the kibana .zip package from elastic.co website
2. Unpack the zip to a folder of your choosing
3. Open the `config\kibana.yml` file with your favorite editor
4. Uncomment the following lines and set the target directory and file name for your logfile.

```
# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
elasticsearch.logQueries: true

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
logging.dest: D:\kibana-7.9.2-windows-x86_64\logs\kibana.log

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
logging.verbose: true
```

5. Launch a `powershell` or `cmd` and navigate to the kibana directory
6. Run `PS D:\kibana-7.9.2-windows-x86_64> .\bin\kibana.bat`
7. Navigate to the logfile directory and open the logfile with your favorite editor.

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-02T19:39:41Z","tags":["debug","server"],"pid":35608,"message":"setting up server"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-02T19:39:41Z","tags":["debug","plugins-service"],"pid":35608,"message":"Discovering plugins"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-02T19:39:41Z","tags":["debug","plugins-discovery"],"pid":35608,"message":"Discovering plugins..."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-02T19:39:41Z","tags":["debug","plugins-discovery"],"pid":35608,"message":"Scanning \"D:\\kibana-7.9.2-windows-x86_64\\src\\plugins\" for plugin sub-directories..."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-02T19:39:41Z","tags":["debug","plugins-discovery"],"pid":35608,"message":"Scanning
```

PS: I've tested with verbose, but you can choose other log-levels (read the instructions in the `kibana.yml` file)